# Geckodriver asking for location. How to remove promts

Tags: bash, geckodriver

When installing geckodriver on ubuntu using `apt install firefox-geckodriver` I get promt saying :

> Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration questions will narrow this down by
> presenting a list of cities, representing the time zones in which they are located.

> 1. Africa   3. Antarctica  5. Arctic  7. Atlantic  9. Indian    11. SystemV  13. Etc
> 2. America  4. Australia   6. Asia    8. Europe    10. Pacific  12. US

> Geographic area:

Since this needs manual input, I am unable to run this in docker-compose.
How to remove this prompt or supply default input options in command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND` env variable should help, try running with `noninteractive` option

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
you can try:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=utc/UTC
RUN apt-get install -y [program]
```

- TZ being your preferred timezone

You can `wget` the latest release tarball from github, extract it and than move it to
your `PATH` or add the path to geckodriver to `PATH`

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar xvfz geckodriver*
chmod +x geckodriver 
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```

Assuming /usr/local/bin is in your `PATH`

Comment: After doing this I got following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line`

Comment: Have you installed firefox? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu:20.04 image. Not sure if it comes with Firefox. 
When I try ‘apt install Firefox’  - I get the same prompt asking me to choose the region